# Using Regular Expressions to match single equals sign only

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to build a regular expression (in JavaScript) that  would match = but not !=, <=, >=, '= and ==. I've figured out everything but ==:

```
text.match(/[^!<>']=/) != null
```

I've failed everything I've tried to ignore ==. Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this, which also allows the equal sign to be at the very beginning or at the very end of your string:

```
/(^|[^!><'=])=($|[^=])/
```

but note that the matching result will contain the characters to the left and to the right of the equal sign, if there are any.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks. I don't care about what it returns, just whether it finds a match or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
text.match(/[^=<>!']=[^=]/)
```